# When to close Statement when using jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, memory-leaks

I am using odbc to connect mysql database in Java

I write a function "ExecuteQuery", it takes a string parameter as sql statement and returns its resultset. However, when should I close the statement object?
If I close it in function ExecuteQuery, the returned resultset will be closed as well.
If I don't close it, memory leak occurs as I do not have the reference of statement object in caller.  Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're taking wrong approach. If you really need such function (which is doubtful), make it accept a `Statement` as a parameter and make a separate function to create and set up that statement. Then you may wrap your function and `ResultSet` work in a `try..finally` block and close the statement in `finally`.

E.g.

```
Statement statement = getStatement();
try {
    ResultSet rs = executeQuery(statement, query);
    ...
} finally {
    statement.close();
}
```

However, if you're facing such problems, you may want to re-consider your architecture. Take a look at [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/), for example.

Comment: Then what approach should I use?

Comment: @Bear Depends on your situation. But you're making a meaningless wrapper above JDBC, which doesnt even make your code cleaner. I suggest you either use a pure JDBC or switch to Hibernate (see [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-Relational_Mapping))